# arm neon inline assemble "mov" difference between clang and gcc

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, neon

Have this problem with the arm neon inline assembler:

```
mov v5.4s, v8.4s
```

The instruction is compiles using clang, but GCC produces the following error :(if I use `mov v5.16b,v8.16b` this is fine):

```
/var/folders/ln/2jr6sq855753h7fjrg_g6hm80000gq/T//ccUbsZid.s: Assembler 
messages:
/var/folders/ln/2jr6sq855753h7fjrg_g6hm80000gq/T//ccUbsZid.s:38355: 
Error: operand mismatch -- `mov v5.4s,v8.4s'
//ccUbsZid.s:38355:Info:did you mean this?
//ccUbsZid.s:38355:Info:mov v5.8b,v8.8b
//ccUbsZid.s:38355:Info:other valid variant(s):
//ccUbsZid.s:38355:Info:mov v5.16b,v8.16b
```

I wonder what causes the error in GCC. In my opinion, `mov` is equal to copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple whole register copy, hence the element type is irrelevant.

The assembly instruction actually only supports `8b` and `16b` specifying double or quad register, and thus, GCC is correct in this while Clang is more tolerant, albeit misleading to some degree like this case.

Honestly, I don't like the `aarch64` assembly syntax.

On `aarch32`, the data type is specified by the instruction suffix while it is done by the register suffix on `aarch64` which you have to attach to ALL operand registers.

This new syntax isn't only annoying, but also causes problems.

A simple `vmov q5, q8` would be enough in this case on `aarch32` without any hassle.